# How to join two tables when one column is null?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`.

`t1` has three coloumns `a`,`b`,`c` and `t2` has two coloumns `x`,`y`.

I want to join these two tables on `t2.x=t1.c`. It is working for me though real problem comes when `t1.c` is `null`. How can I solve the problem. I am using Codeigniter Active Record class and mysql.

Comment: Show your current code...

Comment: I think you are using left/right join. But you should use inner join or simply join

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - I think he's actually having the complete opposite problem.

Comment: Didn't any of the answer help you?

Comment: @hims056: yes,
$this->db->join('t2', 't1.x = t2.c', 'left');

Comment: @user1441638 - Then you should accept his answer. :)

Comment: @hims056: thnx for pointing out that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Code Igniter - you need to specify the 3rd parameter of the join function. Example:

`$this->db->join('t2', 't1.x = t2.c', 'left');`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t2 
    LEFT JOIN t1
    ON t2.x = t1.c
```

This will show records of t2 even t1.c is `NULL`.